# Is possible this manipulation in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a function like

```
function abc() {
  console.log(this);
}
```

And I have a simple variable like

```
var x = 'x';
```

If I do `abc()` will log *Window*. What I need to do for `abc()` print the value of `x`?

Comment: Have you tried `abc.call(x)` ?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_output.asp is that what you are looking for? different methods to display text / variables.

Comment: `console.log(x)`? Which part are you willing to change? What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method 1:**

```
function abc() {
  console.log(this);
}
var x = 'x';
```

Then use this:

```
abc.call(x)
> String {0: "x", length: 1, [[PrimitiveValue]]: "x"}
```

**Method 2:**

```
 function abc(arg) {
     console.log(arg);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the first method! It's what I need. I can't use the second method.

Answer (score 0):

Your function should accept a parameter.

```
function abc(param) {
  console.log(param);
}
```

You can call the function as follows

```
var x = 'x';
abc(x); //or abc('x');
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I can't use a parameter in abc().

Answer (score 0):

If you want to log a particular value in console, pass that value as parameter to the function and use that parameter in console.log call.

```
    function abc(yourParameter)
    {
        console.log(yourParameter);
    }

    var x = 5;
    abc(x);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I can't use a parameter in abc().

Comment: You can use a global parameter :P